# What is a background assumption?

Tags: social-psychology, sociology

What is meant by *background assumption*?

Comment: Good questions should contain some background - where did you read/heard  about this term? Why is it important to you? What was the context where you encountered it?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  If this is a terminology question, then it may be better suited for english.SE or philosophy.SE - for psych.SE, please explain how this question is related to psychology or neuroscience.  I am closing the question for now, but it can be reopened once edited.

Answer (score 2):

A background assumption is something implied or assumed by what you say, but not explicitly stated.

For instance, if you say 'I feel happy'.  It is implied or assumed that you exist.  It is also implied or assumed that happiness exists.  It is implied and assumed that you have feelings.  It is implied that you have told the truth rather than a lie. A background assumption is that you and I both interpret happiness in a similar way.

Many things we say include background or implied assumptions.  Fortunately, most people make similar background assumptions which means that they don't need to be stated, which greatly aids in efficient communication.

Did you notice that I made the assumption that we all make similar background assumptions?

This question may be better directed to https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since the OP didn't give context there is no way of knowing for sure. What you refer to I have always known as implicit premises as part of argumentation, but I also thought of this when the OP referred to 'background assumptions'.